# Python Multiprocessing remote manager: failure to connect when using BaseManager.start() instead of .server().serve_forever()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I'm following an example from the official python documentation here:

I'm trying to make it so that I spin up a `BaseManager` at `localhost:50000` which registers a queue, then a bunch of workers that read from that queue. I can get it to work if I use the method in the official python docs that has three files (one server, one put client, one get client), but I can't get it to work all in one file where I spawn the clients via `multiprocessing.Process(target=...)`.

Here is my full code. The issue is that when the clients attempt to connect they get a `ConnectionRefused` (stack trace below)

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, Any, List
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, SyncManager
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import argparse
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def parse_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    a.add_argument("--n-workers", type=int, default=2)
    return a.parse_args()

def run_queue_server(args: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
    class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
    QueueManager.register("get_queue", lambda: q)
    m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    m.start()

def _worker_process(worker_uid: str) -> None:
    class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
    QueueManager.register("get_queue")
    m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    # <-- This line fails with ConnectionRefused -->
    m.connect()
    queue: queue.Queue = m.get_queue()

def spawn_workers(args: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
    time.sleep(2)
    worker_procs = dict()
    for i in range(args.n_workers):
        print(f"Spawning worker process {i}..")
        p = mp.Process(target=_worker_process, args=[str(i)])
        p.start()
        worker_procs[str(i)] = p

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    run_queue_server(args)
    spawn_workers(args)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is here

```
$ python minimal.py
Spawning worker process 0..
Spawning worker process 1..
Process Process-2:
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "minimal.py", line 26, in _worker_process
    m.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 548, in connect
    conn = Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 629, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "minimal.py", line 26, in _worker_process
    m.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 548, in connect
    conn = Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 629, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

However, If I spawn another process that targets the manager creatoin step and run `m.get_server().serve_forever()` then I *do not* get the connection-refused error, see this code below which works

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, Any, List
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, SyncManager
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import argparse
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def parse_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    a.add_argument("--n-workers", type=int, default=2)
    return a.parse_args()

def run_queue_server(args: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
    class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
    QueueManager.register("get_queue", lambda: q)
    m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    #m.start()
    # This works!!
    m.get_server().serve_forever()

def _worker_process(worker_uid: str) -> None:
    class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
    QueueManager.register("get_queue")
    m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    m.connect()
    queue: queue.Queue = m.get_queue()
    print(f"Gotten queue: {queue}")

def spawn_workers(args: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
    time.sleep(2)
    worker_procs = dict()
    for i in range(args.n_workers):
        print(f"Spawning worker process {i}..")
        p = mp.Process(target=_worker_process, args=[str(i)])
        p.start()
        worker_procs[str(i)] = p

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    #run_queue_server(args)
    # I don't want to run this in another process?
    mp.Process(target=run_queue_server, args=(args,)).start()
    spawn_workers(args)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The thing is, I don't want to have to start another process to be the manager.. why can't it just be this process?

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I'm an idiot who was programming too late into the night. The issue is that my `run_queue_server` when calling `m.start()` and returning was... then losing the reference to the `QueueManager` which I'm sure caused it to be garbage collected.

All I did was change

```
def run_queue_server(args: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
    class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
    QueueManager.register("get_queue", lambda: q)
    m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    m.start()
    return m
```

and change the caller to accept the return value and everything works..